# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribeTo' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to use the @capacitor-community/fcm for push notification but i got this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribeTo' of undefined

I am using ionic framework cli 5...
looks like all the methods gives the same error

This is my .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {
  Plugins,
  PushNotification,
  PushNotificationToken,
  PushNotificationActionPerformed
} from '@capacitor/core';


const { PushNotifications, Modals,FCMPlugin } = Plugins;

import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';
const fcm = new FCM();


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    
    
    PushNotifications.register() .then(() => {
     
  
     FCMPlugin.subscribeTo({ topic: 'all' })
        .then((r) => alert(`subscribed to topic`))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
    
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a platform check?  if (this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('ios')) { // code here }  [FCMPlugin is not defined (before ready)
](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/177)

Comment: thanks for your comment, i will try it out asap

Comment: still not working same error

Answer (score 0):

add this :

on your MainActivity.java file add import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin; and then inside the init callback add(FCMPlugin.class);

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: i dont think this is a good solution since when i did this I got alot of other errors and the app wont even launch

Answer (score 0):

I know im late, but shouldn't be: (remove FCMplugin and use the constant fcm)

```
const { PushNotifications, Modals } = Plugins;

fcm.subscribeTo({ topic: 'all' })
    .then((r) => alert(`subscribed to topic`))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Not FCMplugin...